# What is triggering Unobtrusive Validation check in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm trying to figure out how unobtrusive validation works in asp.net mvc 3.

I would like to know what is triggering the validation check when I click to submit the form. How is the script jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js bound to the form submit event ?

I also would like to know how can I manually prevent/trigger this check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`jquery.validate.unobtrusive` is a validator for `jquery.validate`. It is like a extension.

`jquery.validate.unobtrusive` implements all the events and `jquery.validate` use it.

You can look into the jQuery.validate.js file and see that it uses the submit of the 
form.

```
// validate the form on submit
this.submit( function( event ) {
   ...
```

If you want to trigger the validation by yourself you can call

```
$("#myform").valid()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I've figured out that `$("#myform").validate()` do not work to trigger unobtrusive validation I've got to call `$("#myform").valid()` for the unobtrusive validation to be triggered. Does that sound normal to you ?

Comment: Oh yes right. I mixed it up. Sorry for the confusion. My answer is updated.

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer you've pointed me to the right direction :-) I didn't realized that jquery unobtrusive validation is an extension the the actual jquery validate.